# use tensorflow.GPUOptions within Keras when using tensorflow backend

Tags: tensorflow, keras

In tensorflow I can do something like this when creating a session:

```
tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.333,allow_growth=True)
```

Is there a way to do the same in keras with the tensorflow backend?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set the Keras global tensorflow session with `keras.backend.tensorflow_backend.set_session()`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend.tensorflow_backend as ktf


def get_session(gpu_fraction=0.333):
    gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=gpu_fraction,
                                allow_growth=True)
    return tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))


ktf.set_session(get_session())
```