# No classification improvements with using set_session() for Keras

Tags: session, tensorflow, configuration, keras

I want to use the allow_growth configuration with Keras and tensorflow backend.
As suggested f. e. in [use tensorflow.GPUOptions within Keras when using tensorflow backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41762272/use-tensorflow-gpuoptions-within-keras-when-using-tensorflow-backend) I implemented my code as follows:

```
import keras.backend.tensorflow_backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
...

gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True)
config = tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options)
sess = tf.Session(config = config)
K.set_session(sess)


model = Sequential()
model.add(...)
...
model.compile(...)
model.fit(...)
```

With nvidia-smi I can see, that dynamic allocation works. But with this adaption applied, I'm not able to achieve any improvements in the classification accuracy, which means that the validation error remains the same over multiple epochs.

Hope you can help me.

EDIT:
Output of the first 10 epochs:

Epoch 1/30
307/307 [==============================] - 45s 147ms/step - loss: 3.7766 - acc: 0.0558 - val_loss: 3.7457 - val_acc: 0.0420

Epoch 2/30
307/307 [==============================] - 43s 140ms/step - loss: 3.7372 - acc: 0.0566 - val_loss: 3.7309 - val_acc: 0.0420

Epoch 3/30
307/307 [==============================] - 44s 143ms/step - loss: 3.7222 - acc: 0.0566 - val_loss: 3.7170 - val_acc: 0.0420

Epoch 4/30
307/307 [==============================] - 45s 146ms/step - loss: 3.7079 - acc: 0.0566 - val_loss: 3.7037 - val_acc: 0.0420

Epoch 5/30
307/307 [==============================] - 46s 150ms/step - loss: 3.6944 - acc: 0.0566 - val_loss: 3.6911 - val_acc: 0.0420

Epoch 6/30
307/307 [==============================] - 45s 147ms/step - loss: 3.6815 - acc: 0.0565 - val_loss: 3.6793 - val_acc: 0.0420

Epoch 7/30
307/307 [==============================] - 44s 144ms/step - loss: 3.6693 - acc: 0.0566 - val_loss: 3.6680 - val_acc: 0.0420

Epoch 8/30
307/307 [==============================] - 44s 143ms/step - loss: 3.6577 - acc: 0.0566 - val_loss: 3.6573 - val_acc: 0.0420

Epoch 9/30
307/307 [==============================] - 45s 147ms/step - loss: 3.6467 - acc: 0.0566 - val_loss: 3.6473 - val_acc: 0.0420

Epoch 10/30
307/307 [==============================] - 44s 143ms/step - loss: 3.6363 - acc: 0.0565 - val_loss: 3.6378 - val_acc: 0.0420

Comment: What makes you think that setting that option will improve or change classification accuracy?

Comment: With setting that option I don't want to improve the classification performance. What I mean is that if I add line 3-6 the accuracy does not increase during the model training. 
But if I run the script without line 3-6 the training shows the expected behaviour: accuracy increases and converges during the training.

Comment: Ah now I understand, does the loss change change at all if you use those options?

Comment: See the pasted output of the first 10 epochs I've added to the question above. I use augmented data for training, so that the passed training samples can vary between each epoch.